# Script to copy files to folders with the same shared template names

Tags: bash, scripts

Can anyone help me to define a script which would copy multiple files one by one to multiple folders in other destination based on their shared template names?

For example

I have several folders named like `15apr01d_c_000??gr_000??sq_v0?_000??hl_0000?ex.frames` (the question marks are representing different numbers)

my files are in other folder named `15apr01d_c_000??gr_000??sq_v0?_000??hl_0000?ex.frames.region_000.sum-all_000-0??.box`

So what I want is to copy each respective box file to each respective folder as they share the template name `15apr01d_c_000??gr_000??sq_v0?_0000?hl_0000?ex.frames`

Comment: Are there any serial numbers to those ??? or just random numbers?

Comment: just random numbers

Comment: Can you give an example to a file going to a particular folder. I mean exactly and not by using ??

Comment: I want to copy 15apr01d_c_00042gr_00081sq_v02_00003hl_00002ex.frames.region_000.sum-all_000-056.box which is located in /media/first4t/boxes to respective folder 15apr01d_c_00042gr_00081sq_v02_00003hl_00002ex.frames located in /media/first4t/frames

Comment: How many files/folders are there? Do you know?

Comment: I have about 3500 box files which I do want to copy to respective folders  one by one (so also 3500)

Answer (score 0):

The bash script you are looking for is:

```
#!/bin/bash

#for loop

for n in {1..3500}

do

cp -r `find /media/first4t/boxes/ -type f -iname $(cd /media/first4t/frames && ls -d 15apr01d_c_000[0-9][0-9]gr_000[0-9][0-9]sq_v0[0-9]_000[0-9][0-9]hl_0000[0-9]ex.frames | head -$n | awk 'END{print}')* | awk 'END{print}'` /media/first4t/frames/`cd /media/first4t/frames && ls -d 15apr01d_c_000[0-9][0-9]gr_000[0-9][0-9]sq_v0[0-9]_000[0-9][0-9]hl_0000[0-9]ex.frames | head -$n | awk 'END{print}'`/

done
```

Save it as `/path/to/anyname.sh` & to run it do:

```
bash /path/to/anyname.sh
```

Comment: Ok now I am able to run the script, but instead of copying the boxes to respective folders, the script is making another copy of the frame folders with the the respective box file, I want to avoid this to make actually duplicates of frame folders

Comment: Did you edit the script to make it run, if so specify your changes

Comment: I played with it and it works now fine. Thank you so much for help.

Comment: What did you edit? Could you please specigy so that I may edit my answer and then you may accept it as an answer.

Comment: I basically commented the second half of the script which was /media/first4t/frames/`cd /media/first4t/frames && ls -d 15apr01d_c_000[0-9][0-9]gr_000[0-9][0-9]sq_v0[0-9]_000[0-9][0-9]hl_0000[0-9]ex.frames | head -$n | awk 'END{print}'`/ because this part was responsible to copy additionally also the frames folders in duplicate

Comment: Well then, you can edit my answer and then upvote and accept it.

Answer (score -2):

A bit of bash script can so this job quite well. A bit to write the scripts now.

Are you aware of bash script ?

Use rsync !!

Comment: How can I use rsync for this purpose?